# FabricJS - Create rectangle using 4 points (tl,tr, bl, br)?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

Creating a rectangle in FabricJs is straightforward using `top`, `left`, `width` and `height` values.

After moving, scaling and rotating the rectangle around, one can get the rectangle's definitive coordinate using the `aCoords` of the object, returning `bl`, `br`, `tl`, `tr` x and y coordinates of the rectangles four edges.

How can one recreate the same rectangle using only these four coordinates, which also include rotation and scaling?

I was only able to recreate the rectangle after it has been moved and scaled, but not with rotations.

[image: FabricJS create rectangle using only coordinates issue]

This above image is a screenshot of the following jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7neukojd/32/

As you can see, the left side is the original rectangle (blue), which has been scaled, moved and rotated. The right side rectangle (red) is me, trying to copy it using only the `bl`, `br`, `tl` and `tr` coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [asturur](https://github.com/asturur), this issue has been solved with the following code

```js
  let rectObj = canvas1.getObjects()[0];
  const tl = rectObj.aCoords.tl;
  const tr = rectObj.aCoords.tr;
  const bl = rectObj.aCoords.bl;
  
  let rectCopy = new fabric.Rect({
    left: rectObj.aCoords.tl.x,
    top:  rectObj.aCoords.tl.y,
    width: (new fabric.Point(tl.x, tl.y).distanceFrom(tr)),
    height: (new fabric.Point(tl.x, tl.y).distanceFrom(bl)),
    angle: fabric.util.radiansToDegrees(Math.atan2(tr.y - tl.y, tr.x - tl.x)),
    fill: "red",
  })
```

Source: https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/discussions/6834#discussioncomment-314599